# Download SVG content as PNG file, Following code is working fine in chrome but not working in IE browser.Any suggestions?

Tags: javascript

Download SVG content as PNG file, Following code is working fine in chrome but not working in IE browser.Any suggestions?

.

```
var svg = document.querySelector( "svg" );
var svgData = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString( svg );
var canvas = document.createElement( "canvas" );

var svgSize = svg.getBoundingClientRect();
canvas.width = svgSize.width;
canvas.height = svgSize.height;
var ctx = canvas.getContext( "2d" );
var img = document.createElement( "img" );
img.setAttribute( "src", "data:image/svg+xml;base64," + btoa( svgData ) );


img.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage( img, 0, 0 );

    setTimeout(function(){
        var a = document.createElement("a");
        a.download = "networkmap.png";
        a.href = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");console.log(a.href);
        a.click();
     }, 500);       
};
```

Comment: First suggestion: describe the problem. What does not work? are there errors in the browser console? If yes, which ones...

Comment: There is no errors in the browser console. I am trying to download SVG content as PNG file. The above code is working fine in Chrome browser.

Answer (score 0):

`data:image/svg+xml;` seems fishy for a Canvas/PNG element, `data:image/png` is the right Mime-Type for PNG.

Comment: I am using firefox 44.0.2 version.